# Extracting the monthly evaporation time series from Google Earth Engine for a point

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

I am trying to get a time series of monthly evaporation for a point, but I get the error message:

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
User memory limit exceeded.
```

Apparently there is an error somewhere that I can't identify.

Here is the script:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-8.620027,31.363085]);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
          .filterBounds(point)
          .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31')
          .select('total_evaporation');

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var start_year = 2000;
var start_date = '2000-01-01';
var end_year = 2017;
var end_date = '2017-12-31';

var years = ee.List.sequence( start_year, end_year);


var byMonthYear =  ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var w = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .mean();
           
      var pointMean = w.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.first(), geometry:point,scale:25000});  
      // set the dictionary as property and cast to an ee.Image, as setMulti returns an ee.Element.
      return ee.Feature(null).set("value",pointMean.get("'total_evaporation'")).set("year",y).set("month",m);
      

    });
  }).flatten()
);


// print the collection, point information
print("feature collection",byMonthYear);

Export.table.toDrive({collection:byMonthYear,description:"csvExport"})
```